# EditText cursor issue on backspace

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a custom EditText class defined on my edittext form items. When I do a backspace on the contents I have this weird multiple cursors visible in the field.

[image]

I did a backspace until the first 'j' in the field and this is how it appears. Here's the custom code I wrote:

```
private class RegistrationEditText extends EditText {

    boolean required;
    private String key;
    private boolean isQuestion = false;
    private String questionKey;

    public RegistrationEditText(boolean required) {
        super(Activity.this);
        this.required = required;
    }

    public String getValue() { return this.getText().toString(); }

    public void setKey(String key) { this.key = key; }
    public String getKey() { return this.key; }

    public void setIsQuestion(boolean value) { this.isQuestion = value; }
    public boolean getIsQuestion() { return this.isQuestion; }

    public void setQuestionKey(String value) { this.questionKey = value; }
    public String getQuestionKey() { return this.questionKey; }

    public boolean validate() {
        // Validations
    }
}
```

This is happening on 4.4 and below. On Lollipop it just works fine. Happens on variety of phones. Please let me know if I'm missing something or if extending EditText is a bad idea

Comment: In your case I don't think there is much use in overriding EditText, especially since you don't use the constructor with the `AttributeSet` parameter.

Comment: Maybe you missed calling super method in some overriden method?

Comment: @njzk2 I'm new to android so I'm not yet aware of `AttributeSet` and it's relevance to EditText's constructor. So what I understand from your suggestion is that I don't need a special class to set the attributes like key and isQuestion? If so can you please let me know how setting of attributes can be done for EditTexts? I simple followed this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27230487/creating-and-setting-custom-edittext-attributes

Comment: @DjDexter5GHz I haven't overridden any methods there as you see. I'm calling super from constructor. Do you think I should override any TextWatcher methods?

Comment: No, i think those are still fine if you called super constructor. But something is still wrong here. I would suggest to use external class to implement functionality and not extend EditText.

Comment: Turns out it' an issue with EditText background. I couldn't solve it but for now removing the background works fine

Answer (score 0):

It looks the problem is with view customization , else the code is working fine on Android 4.0.4 and 2.3.

Following code is working fine-

```
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        RegistrationEditText registrationEditText = new RegistrationEditText(false, getActivity());
        registrationEditText.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.text_box));
        linearLayout.addView(registrationEditText);
```

Post your implementation in the code to understand the complete issue.